# Inserting data from MySQL database into DataGridView

Tags: mysql, vb.net, forms, datagridview

I have a MySQL database with the columns TIME and METHOD, which have about 15,000+ rows of data. I need to get these columns/rows to display on a DataGridView within a vb.net form. I am using the MySql.Data.dll to connect to the database and run my queries. Below is my current code:

```
Private Sub RetreiveData() Handles Button.click
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim connectionString As String = "server=ipaddress;database=debugging;user id=root;password=password;port=3307"
    Dim connection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(connectionString)

    Try
        connection.Open()
        Dim sql As String = String.Format("SELECT time, method FROM test1 WHERE custPin='{0}' AND dataID='{1}' ORDER BY TIME;", customerPin, sessionID)
        Dim dAdapter As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(Sql, connection)
        dAdapter.Fill(dt)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " & ex.Message & Environment.NewLine & ex.StackTrace & Environment.NewLine)
        If connection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            connection.Close()
        End If
    End Try

    Me.dgvCustomerData.DataSource = dt
    connection.Close()
End Sub
```

Note: "dgvCustomerData" is my DataGridView on my form, and "customerPin"/"sessionID" are retrieved from TextBoxes on my form as well.

I have checked through about 20-30 forum posts that state I should bind my data, or use different styles of data adapters, but none have been able to display my data. I can get it to create the two columns, however, no data is filled in. Any assistance would be very helpful, thanks in advanced.

Comment: If `custPin` or `dataID` are numeric columns in the DB, you are passing them as string. Ticks (`'`) are not general purpose SQL delimiters